# Jackson one item parse

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to parse openweathermap.org api

WeatheModel.java

```
public class WeatherModel {

private ListDays[] listDays;

@JsonProperty("list")
public ListDays[] getListDays() {
    return listDays;
}
```

and two classes here http://pastebin.com/vySPfRSS

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static final String WEATHER = "JSON from http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7"

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    WeatherModel rootNode = mapper.readValue(WEATHER, WeatherModel.class);
```

How to get one (now it a list of 7 items ) item from WeatherModel?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the index to access object from an array.

```
ListDays[] listDays = rootNode.getListDays();
ListDays first = listDays[0];
ListDays second = listDays[1];
```

Arrays are sequences of objects and in the case above you describe an array of 7 `ListDays`. The *first* object uses index 0, the second object uses index 1 and so on. The `[0]` simply means that you retrieve the first object from the array. The length of the array can be determined by invoking `listDays.length`.

To loop  through all of the elements you can use a `for`-loop.

```
for (ListDays l : listDays) {
    // Here you have access to one ListDays-object. It is called l.
    l.doStuff...
}
```